# change a html cell border based on value pulled in by ajax

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

EDIT: so after making some minor changes based on your suggestions i now get

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toggleClass' of undefined

I have a html table created by for loop  that im trying to change the border colour based on delivery_avg which is pulled in using ajax

I can get it to work so that the border changed on the location(a colour) but cant get it to change on delivery avg  as you can see from below im trying to get it to change to lime if value is below 10, orange if between 10 and 20 and pink if between 20 and 30

the data transferred by ajax is displayed like this:

```
{beacon: "59", location: "YELLOW", delivery_avg: "04.48"}
```

so it would hopefully mean the cell border changed to lime but its staying its original colour of black.

does any one have any idea's where i have gone wrong?

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>

<html>
  <head>
    <title>Table</title>
    <style>
    table {
        padding: 10px 30px;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }

    table, td, th {
        border: 1px solid black;    
        cellpadding: 5;
        cellspacing: 5;
        text-align: center; 
        vertical-align: middle;
        font-size: 40px;
        background-color: #8F8F8F;
    }
    </style>
    <script> <!-- see javascript below --> </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table id='zoning'>
      <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
function addColor() {
{
    if (item.delivery_avg <= 10.00) {
        return ('border-color', 'lime','border-width', 'thick');
    } else if (item.delivery_avg>= 10.01 && item.delivery_avg<= 20.00) {
        return ('border-color', 'brightorange','border-width', 'thick');
    } else if (item.delivery_avg>= 20.01 && item.delivery_avg<= 30.00) {
        return ('border-color', 'pink','border-width', 'thick');
    }
};
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        var row = $('<tr>').appendTo("#zoning tbody");
        for (var j = 1; j < 11; j++) {
            $(`<td class='${i * 10 + j}'>${i * 10 + j}</td>`).appendTo(row);
        }
    }

    $.get('php/beacon.php', function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        var row;
        response.forEach(function(item, index) {
            console.log(item);
function addColor() {
{
    if (item.delivery_avg <= 10.00) {
        return ('border-color', 'lime','border-width', 'thick');
    } else if (item.delivery_avg>= 10.01 && item.delivery_avg<= 20.00) {
        return ('border-color', 'brightorange','border-width', 'thick');
    } else if (item.delivery_avg>= 20.01 && item.delivery_avg<= 30.00) {
        return ('border-color', 'pink','border-width', 'thick');
    }
};
}
            $(`td.${item.beacon}`).css(addColor() ).toggleClass('coloured');
        });
    });


        function updateTable() {
        //console.log('function called');
        $('td.coloured').css('border-color','black').toggleClass('coloured');
        $.get('php/beacon.php', function(response) {
            response.forEach(function(item, index) {
                console.log(item.beacon);
                //$('td.coloured').css('border-color','#black').toggleClass('coloured');
        $(`td.${item.beacon}`).css(addColor()).toggleClass('coloured');
            });
        });

    }
    var updateTableInterval = setInterval(updateTable, 30000);
});
```

Comment: You have two functions named add color(). That isn't the entire issue, but the second one overrides the first one. Rename one of them, or combine them.

Comment: oh okay thank you for that i thought putting it like that would just run the function the idea is after so long the update table function runs and if the data isnt being pulled in any more change the border back to black

Comment: Secondly, a simpler approach would be to setup your colors with css class names so you don't have to assemble styles in JavaScript. Then, check your incoming data and use jQuery's .addClass('yourClassName') or .removeClass('yourClassName') as a simpler means of changing colors.

Comment: sorry im not great at this what type of thing would i put as an example?

i did have another lot of code that changed text using the same sort of idea but was written in php and it used echo "<td style=\"color:" . addColor($row['delivery_avg']) . "\">";
            echo $row['delivery_avg'];
 to call the function

Comment: Regarding changing the color back to black after a period of time, your plan makes sense, but you will need to implement the idea differently. That part, may end up needing a separate question to get the best responses.

Comment: okay thank you ill look into that

Comment: No worries, we are here to help. Both answers look promising and more specific than my comments here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to change up the code to resolve this issue using the following:

```
function updateTable() {
        //console.log('function called');
        $('td.coloured').css('background-
color','#8F8F8F').toggleClass('coloured');
        $.get('php/del.php', function(response) {
            response.forEach(function(item, index) {
                console.log(item.beacon);
                //$('td.coloured').css('background-color','#8F8F8F').toggleClass('coloured');
        $(`td.${item.beacon}`).css('background-color', item.location).toggleClass('coloured');
        if (item.delivery_avg <= 10.00) {
                return $(`td.${item.beacon}`).css({'border-color':'lime', 'border-width':'thick' }).toggleClass('coloured');
             } else if (item.delivery_avg >= 10.01 && item.delivery_avg <= 20.00) {
                 return $(`td.${item.beacon}`).css({'border-color':'orange', 'border-width':'thick' }).toggleClass('coloured');
             } else if (item.delivery_avg >= 20.01 && item.delivery_avg <= 30.00) {
                return $(`td.${item.beacon}`).css({'border-color':'pink', 'border-width':'thick' }).toggleClass('coloured');
              }
            });
        });

    }
    var updateTableInterval = setInterval(updateTable, 5000);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to replace this

```
('border-color', 'lime','border-width', 'thick')
```

with this:

```
{'border-color':'lime', 'border-width':'thick' }
```

If you were defining the CSS in the jQuery call, the following updates the CSS [using class notation](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-properties):

```
$(`td.${item.beacon}`).css({'border-color':'lime', 'border-width':'thick' }).toggleClass('coloured');
```

Note: jQuery supports 'border-color' or 'borderColor' according to the docs:

> Also, jQuery can equally interpret the CSS and DOM formatting of
>   multiple-word properties. For example, jQuery understands and returns
>   the correct value for both .css({ "background-color": "#ffe",
>   "border-left": "5px solid #ccc" }) and .css({backgroundColor: "#ffe",
>   borderLeft: "5px solid #ccc" }). Notice that with the DOM notation,
>   quotation marks around the property names are optional, but with CSS
>   notation they're required due to the hyphen in the name.

**EDIT**: In your example above, in the callback of `$.get`, pass in the parameter to the addcolor function, and then change the addColor function to be outside the $.get function (there should only be 1 definition - just noting because I see 2 above):

```
function addColor(item) {
{
    if (item.delivery_avg <= 10.00) {
        return { 'border-color': 'lime','border-width': 'thick' };
    } else if (item.delivery_avg>= 10.01 && item.delivery_avg<= 20.00) {
        return {'border-color': 'brightorange','border-width': 'thick' };
    } else if (item.delivery_avg>= 20.01 && item.delivery_avg<= 30.00) {
        return { 'border-color': 'pink','border-width': 'thick' };
    }
};

.
.


$.get('php/beacon.php', function(response) {
    console.log(response);
    var row;
    response.forEach(function(item, index) {
        console.log(item);

        $('td." + item.beacon + "').css( addColor(item) ).toggleClass('coloured');
    });
});
```

Note if it isn't finding it, make sure the `$('td...'` selector is actually finding it.

Comment: i thought it was a colon instead of comma but that seems to stop my table from creating

Comment: okay so manged to get that working how can i write it so that the colour changes based on the values as in the add colour function? thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your return statements in addColor are wrong. The actual value you are returning is always "thick", the last element.
What you should return is an object of property-value pairs to pass the jquery css method (see http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-properties) :

```
if (item.delivery_avg <= 10.00) {
    return ('border-color', 'lime','border-width', 'thick');
```

should become

```
if (item.delivery_avg <= 10.00) {
    return { borderColor : 'lime', borderWidth : 'thick' };
```